# inner join with group by and finding count of repeated values in a column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL databse.

I have the tables `job`, `job_application`, `interview` and their structure is as below :

**job** table:

```
select * from job;
```

[image]

**job_application** table

```
select * from job_application;
```

[image]

**interview** table:

```
select * from interview;
```

[image]

I have prepared a query to get some data by joining above tables something like below(of course, my actual requirement is slightly different and that I will explain later):

```
SELECT job_description,
       i1.interview_type,
       hired,
       open_positions - hired   AS remaining,
       Count(i1.interview_type) AS current_count
FROM   job
       INNER JOIN job_application j1
               ON job.id = j1.job_id
       INNER JOIN interview i1
               ON j1.id = i1.jobapplication_id
GROUP  BY i1.interview_type,
          job_description,
          hired,
          open_positions;
```

The above query will result data something like below:
[image]

But my actual requirement is to get the count of each `interview_type`(L1, L2, HR etc...from `interview` table) against the `job_description`.
For example something like below:
[image]

Can anyone guide/explain me how to get the data in the above format from the query that I have already prepared? Please let me know if you need any information.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck with CrossTab ([PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)).

But I got there without it using:

```
SELECT 
    job.job_description
    ,job.hired
    ,job.open_positions - job.hired AS remaining
    ,COALESCE(L1.cnt, 0) AS L1
    ,COALESCE(L2.cnt, 0) AS L2
    ,COALESCE(HR.cnt, 0) AS HR
    ,COALESCE(EXECUTIVE.cnt, 0) AS EXECUTIVE
FROM job

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    ja.job_id
    ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM job_application ja

INNER JOIN interview i1
ON ja.id = i1.jobapplication_id
    
WHERE i1.interview_type = 'L1'

GROUP BY
    ja.job_id
) AS L1
ON L1.job_id = job.id

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    ja.job_id
    ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM job_application ja

INNER JOIN interview i1
ON ja.id = i1.jobapplication_id
    
WHERE i1.interview_type = 'L2'

GROUP BY
    ja.job_id
) AS L2
ON L2.job_id = job.id

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    ja.job_id
    ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM job_application ja

INNER JOIN interview i1
ON ja.id = i1.jobapplication_id
    
WHERE i1.interview_type = 'HR'

GROUP BY
    ja.job_id
) AS HR
ON HR.job_id = job.id

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    ja.job_id
    ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM job_application ja

INNER JOIN interview i1
ON ja.id = i1.jobapplication_id
    
WHERE i1.interview_type = 'EXECUTIVE'

GROUP BY
    ja.job_id
) AS EXECUTIVE
ON EXECUTIVE.job_id = job.id;
```

In other words doing a join to the SQL query to Job_application and interview tables and filtering to each interview type (which wouldn't be advisable if there were many more interview types).